# How to resolve the Composer dependencies conflicts symfony 7 ? Install FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm writing a PHP application based on Symfony v6. Now I want to upgrade Symfony to the 7.0.
And I have problem with install FOSUserBundle
`composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "^3.0"`

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "^3.0"
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v3.0.0, ..., v3.0.2] require symfony/config ^4.4 || ^5.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.31] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (7.0.*).
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v3.1.0, ..., v3.2.1] require symfony/config ^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.31, v6.0.0, ..., v6.4.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (7.0.*).
    - Root composer.json requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v3.0.0, ..., v3.2.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Is it possible to install FOSUserBundel for Symfony7?

Answer (score 0):

The 7th version has just been released.

The latest version of FosUserBundle is 3.2.1, and the [composer.json](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/composer.json)  of this version only allows the following versions:

- ^4.4
- ^5.0
- ^6.0

The answer is: Not yet.